# Switch < or > value case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm just wondering if there's a way to make this sort of thing work in a switch statement, I'm aware that it's very possible in an else if statement but I would prefer to go with a switch statement, below I've attached an example piece of code to show what I mean...

```js
let money = 42;

switch (money) {
  case < 10:
    console.log('You have $10 or less USD');
    break;
  case < 50:
    console.log('You have $50 or less USD');
    break;
  case < 100:
    console.log('You have $100 or less USD');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('You are rich! Over $100);
    break;
}
```

if this worked the way I wanted it would print "You have $50 or less USD" as money is < 50 but > 10.

Thanks in advance, Lachie.

Comment: [Review the syntax for `switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). What you've written is not the correct way to use `switch`. You should probably use `if`/`else` here instead.

Comment: Not with `switch`, no. `switch` always compares exact values. You have to go `if(money<10){ ... } else if(money < 50) { ... } else if(money < 100){ ... } else { ... }`

Comment: You can make switch work this way, but an if/else if makes more sense....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a nice way to do that, notice that `switch(true)` will evaluate each expression.
Not always readable, but nice to know.

```js
const money = 200;

switch (true) {
  case money < 10:
    console.log('You have $10 or less USD');
    break;
  case money < 50:
    console.log('You have $50 or less USD');
    break;
  case money < 100:
    console.log('You have $100 or less USD');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('You are rich! Over $100');
    break;
}
```

Comment: So in this case you have to keep small number at the top always

Comment: @SourabhSomani yeap, it's weird implementation but this shows the concept.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const run = (money) => {
  switch (true) {
    case money < 10:
      console.log('You have $10 or less USD');
      break;
    case money < 50:
      console.log('You have $50 or less USD');
      break;
    case money < 100:
      console.log('You have $100 or less USD');
      break;
    default:
      console.log('You are rich! Over $100');
      break;
  }
};

run(42);
run(55);
run(123);
```

You need to do the comparison with the money that you have.